# Licensing app in android?

Tags: android, android-lvl

I have completed my development  for my app in android. When I go to publish my app. i have to License my application why because its a paid app. so if the your want share the app from the phone to phone then i have to restrict to share or ask for the payment. How to do that in android?

is there possible to publish my app without licensing by selecting copy-protection option as off now and update it later.

Comment: FYI: Using the licensing feature is optional. You should just be able to upload your app without integrating that feature, and without selecting Copy Protection in the Market web UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy protection is going to be removed if it's not already.

As for your first question, did you look at the documentation? What exactly don't you understand. I think google was pretty clear on what the licensing process is http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html

Comment: then is it just for the expiration validity for my app. am i understand it correctly now?

Comment: I think you're talking about signing, that's different. http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: no. i mean that the app has some period of validity for a payment. if that expires user has to pay again. is that right?

Comment: No, users can use the app and receive updates indefinitely once they purchase it.